# Queueable interface invalid

Tags: bug, queueable-interface

I'm trying to deploy everything from my existing (and fully functional) development sandbox to a freshly created sandbox. One of my classes (JobQueueable) implements the Queueable-interface from Salesforce. This class gives the following error when deploying:

*Error: Invalid Interface name provided (line 10, column 27)*

I've tried changing *JobQueueable implements Queueable* to *JobQueueable Implements queueable* according to this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AlPqIAK This only gave me more errors though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought it'd be good to share my solution with you. I ended up contacting Salesforce support and after some messages back and forth it turned out that there's some sort of backend setting that needs switched on:

> Tier 3 has enabled the permission "Apex queueable" in this Org.
>   Now, you should be able to implement queueable
>   interface.

Maybe someone can enlighten me as to why this is not on by default?

Comment: It's likely that it is so new they want to see who is using it and what for, so they keep tabs on it until asked to enable it.  It's not a developer preview or beta, so I don't have any other explanation.

Comment: Not so. It's already enabled in all of my orgs. More likely, it was a *glitch* with their update scripts (i.e. some orgs may have been missed). I've noticed that any time a new feature has a BlackTab permission, it almost always ends up not getting turned on in a small number of orgs (no hard evidence, but maybe 1-5%?).

Comment: Possible, although I created the org in question yesterday afternoon. This may mean it wasn't a glitch in their update scripts? On the other hand, I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that it is a feature that needs requested before being functional.